# creating a function with parameters for a 2d list with python

Tags: python

parameters a and b where a is the passenger number and b is the bag number. the 2d lis provided is

```
x = [[67, 56, 89, 34], [12, 37, 42 ], [78, 39, 31, 49 ]].
```

the function is supposed to read

```
a = 3 (passenger 3)
b = 2 (bag 2)

>>>airplane(3,2)
```

bag #2 is for passenger 3 weights 39lbs.

this is where I'm at so far but I don't know how to assign the variable to the rows in columns.

```
def airplane(a,b):
    x = [[67, 56, 89, 34], [12, 37, 42 ], [78, 39, 31, 49 ]]
    for a in range(len(x)):
        for b in range(len(m[a])):
            print ()
```